# testng.xml does not execute all @Test annotation within the class

Tags: selenium, automation, annotations, testng

I'm trying to run all tests in the project using testng.xml I have 7 @Test method under one class. I used data provider for 2 test method and 5 @test method execute without data provider.

When I execute a class it executes only 1st @test method(test1).
I used dependsonmethods also but it is not working out for me.

```
**@Test class:**
```

```
public class regressionTest{
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getCardTestData() {
        return TestUtil.getTestData(Constants.test1data);
    }
    
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getCardTestDataNeg() {
        return TestUtil.getTestData(Constants.test2data);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1,dataProvider = "getCardTestData", enabled = true){
    public void test1{

    }
   }

   @Test( priority = 2,dataProvider = "getCardTestDataNeg", enabled = true){
public void test2{
}
}

@Test( priority = 3, enabled = true){
public void test3{
}
}

@Test( priority = 4, enabled = true){
public void test4{
}
}

@Test( priority = 5, enabled = true){
public void test5{
}
}

@Test( priority = 6, enabled = true){
public void test6{
}
}

@Test( priority = 7, enabled = true){
public void test7{
}
}
}
```

```
**Testng.xml:**
```

```
     <suite name="Automation Test Suite : Regression">
parameter name="environment" value="qa" />
  <test name="Automation Test Cases : Regression" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        
        <class name="com.regressionTest"></class>

</test>

</suite>
```

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: No i didn't get any error. even it is not showing skipped test case count. it executes 1st test in the class.

Comment: Can you post the whole code from RegressionTest class, this code contains some errors like indentation, in method signature parantheses missing, there are extra curly braces for each method, I don't know why added those.

Comment: Your mentioned code  have error
@Test( priority = 2,dataProvider = "getCardTestDataNeg", enabled = true){
public void test2{
}
}

But it should be like
@Test( priority = 2,dataProvider = "getCardTestDataNeg", enabled = true)
public void test2(){
}

Comment: Can you make sure you are posting relevant example? I believe the code you provided won't even compile..